# A question on convergence.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

If $u_n \rightarrow u$ in $L^p(\Omega)$ and suppose $u_n^{\frac{1}{p-1}}, u^{\frac{1}{p-1}}  \in L^p(\Omega) \forall n$ then can it be said that $u_n^{1/p-1}\rightarrow u^{1/p-1}$ in $L^p(\Omega)$?.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that (the measure of) $\Omega$ is bounded.

This is true for $p \ge 2$ or, rather, for $1/(p-1) \le 1$.

For $p < 2$, you can take $u_n = n^\alpha \, \chi_{[0,1/n]}$ in $L^p(0,1)$ with suitably chosen $\alpha$ to get a counterexample.

Now, let $p \ge 2$ and let $q := 1/(p-1) \le 1$. For arbitrary $x \in \Omega$ we have
$$|u(x)|^q \le |u(x) - u_n(x)|^q + |u_n(x)|^q$$
and
$$|u_n(x)|^q \le |u(x) - u_n(x)|^q + |u(x)|^q.$$
Hence,
$$\big| |u_n(x)|^q - |u(x)|^q \big| \le |u(x) - u_n(x)|^q.$$
Now, we have
\begin{align*}
\|{|u|^q - |u_n|^q}\|_{L^p(\Omega)}^p
&=
\int_\Omega \big| |u_n(x)|^q - |u(x)|^q \big|^p \, \mathrm{d}x
\\
 &\le
\int_\Omega |u(x) - u_n(x)|^{qp} \, \mathrm{d}x
\\&=
\|{u - u_n}\|_{L^{qp}}^{qp}
\end{align*}
Now, since $\Omega$ is bounded, the embedding from $L^p(\Omega)$ to $L^{qp}(\Omega)$ is continuous, since $qp \le p$.

If $\Omega$ is not assumed to be bounded, it may also not hold for $p > 2$. Maybe a counterexample could be something like $u_n(x) = n^\alpha \, \chi_{[0,n]}$ in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So can I say that if $u_n\rightarrow w$ in $L^p(\Omega)$, $u_n \rightharpoonup w$ in $L^{p'}(\Omega)$, $u_n^{1/p-1} \rightharpoonup u$ in $L^{p}(\Omega)$ where $p<2<p'$, then can it be said that $w^{1/p-1}=u$?.

Comment: Yes, this should be sufficient. From the strong convergence of $u_n$, you get pointwise convergence a.e. (along a subsequence). Hence, $u_n^{1/(p-1)} \to w^{1/(p-1)}$ pointwise a.e. Together with its weak convergence, your claim follows.